# How to prove or disapprove the following?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

a)  If $a \mid c$ and $b \mid c$, then $ab \mid c^2$.

b)  If $a \mid (b + c)$, then $a \mid b$ and $a \mid c$.

I am not sure if my answer is correct..

[My answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKGNw.png)

Comment: Your answer to $A$ appears to be correct (but you should have more discussion in a proof and not just symbols).

Comment: Counterexample for the second question: $a=4,b=5,c=7$.

Comment: I wonder when is (b) true. If $c=qb$ it seems to be right, but is this the only case in which the proposition is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For the first is correct your proof: if $a\mid c$ and $b\mid c$, then $c=ak=bq$ for $k,q\in\mathbb{Z}$, so $ab\mid ab(kq)=c^2$.
- For the second part, $a=2$, $b=c=1$ is a counterexample.